# Problem proving a binary add function

Tags: coq, beginner, proof-review

I'm fairly new to the Coq language and I want to prove a function that does an binary add from numbers represented as a list (least significant bit upfront).

I have created this badd function that does that and now I want to prove it

```
Fixpoint badd (l1 l2: list bool): list bool := 
  match l2 with
  | [] => l1
  | true :: l2 =>  bsucc (badd (badd l1 l2) l2)
  | false :: l2 => badd (badd l1 l2) l2
  end.
```

Here is my proof so far (value give the decimal value of the binary number) :

```
Lemma baddOK: forall l1 l2, value (badd l1 l2) = value l1 + value l2.
Proof.
  intros l1 l2.
  generalize dependent l1.
  induction l2; auto.
  rewrite IHl2. (* this fail *)


Admitted.
```

The problem I have now is that I have IHl2 that correspond to

```
IHl2: forall l1 : list bool, value (badd l1 l2) = value l1 + value l2
```

And my goal is :

```
forall l1 : list bool, value (badd l1 (a :: l2)) = value l1 + value (a :: l2)
```

The problem is that I can't rewrite using IHl2 as the generic part of it (i.e. l1) does not match with l3 (i.e. a::l2) but with l1 itself.

Here is the value function to be able to follow the proof:

```
Fixpoint value (l: list bool) :=
  match l with
  | [] => 0
  | true :: l => 2 * (value l) + 1
  | false :: l => 2 * (value l)
  end.
```

Comment: Have you proved that `value (bsucc l) = 1 + value l` ?

Comment: Since the function `badd` matches on `l2` and not `l1`, the rule of thumb is induction on `l2`: This "fits" the structure of the function, and is more likely to work. (Don't forget to generalize `l1` before you make the induction.)

Comment: If you want people to easily replay your proofs, you should give your whole context. For instance, here we lack the definition of `value` to be able to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change your definition of `badd`, then you can try swapping `l1` and `l2`, which is in my opinion more natural:

```
Fixpoint badd (l1 l2: list bool): list bool := 
  match l1 with
  | [] => l2
  | true :: l1 =>  bsucc (badd l1 (badd l1 l2))
  | false :: l1 => badd l1 (badd l1 l2)
  end.
```

But anyway let's use the original `badd`. The ultimate way to prove anything is to **prove it with pen and paper first**. After all, if you can't convince a human, you will never convince your computer! So if you do an induction on `l2`, there will be three cases:

- `l2` is the empty list. In this case you get `value l1 = value l1 + O`, which you probably already proved.
- `l2` begins with `false`, say `false :: l3`. In this case you need to prove `value (badd (badd l1 l3) l3) = value l1 + (value l3 + value l3)`. (You didn't post the definition of `value`, but it will be similar.) In this case, you already decomposed `l2`, and therefore you can use the induction hypothesis, which should be `value (badd l1 l3) = value l1 + value l3`. But now there is a problem applying this hypothesis, because you have `value (badd (badd l1 l3) l3)`, and the first addend is *not* `l1`!

This is where the generalization comes in. Since you only matched `l2`, you should *only* be doing induction on `l2`, and the induction hypothesis should range over *all* `l1`. This is to say, the induction hypothesis *should* be `IH : forall l, value (badd l l3) = value l + value l3`. This would work, because now you can rewrite twice with `IH (badd l1 l3)` and `IH l1`, and finish the goal.

Therefore, before performing the tactic `induction l2`, your goal should be `forall l1, value (badd l1 l2) = value l1 + value l2`, note the forall! To do this, use the tactic `generalize l1` before you do the induction.

Comment: @louga31 As I said, there is three cases. I did not write the third, because I trust that you can figure it out **if you write down a pen and paper proof**. Look at my three cases, can you see what you forgot to do? (Hint: Pen and paper proof is essential.)

Comment: @louga31 Do you mean `unfold`?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use [functional induction](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/using/libraries/funind.html) and [automated solvers](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/micromega.html).

Unfortunately, functional induction doesn't work well over dependent types. The popular [Equations](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations) plugin works better with dependent types but has its own weirdness.

Also this sort of approach isn't necessarily very edifying unless maybe you write the reflection code yourself.

[Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Reflection.html) gives an introduction to proof by reflection although I don't really feel the approach is very structured. Personally I like to structure proof by reflection around [free objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+object) but I still don't really feel I have a fully cohesive grasp of the concept. Unfortunately while the free object for simple cases like monoids is simple and just a list free objects for more complicated cases like rings are more complicated and might require quotients or setoids.

```
Require Coq.Lists.List.

Require Import FunInd.
Require Import Psatz.
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.

Import List.ListNotations.

Function value (l: list bool): nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => 0
  | true :: l => 2 * value l + 1
  | false :: l => 2 * value l
  end %list.

Function bsucc l :=
  match l with
  | [] => [true]
  | false :: t => true :: t
  | true :: t => false :: bsucc t
  end%list.

Function badd (l1 l2: list bool): list bool :=
  match l2 with
  | [] => l1
  | true :: l2 => bsucc (badd (badd l1 l2) l2)
  | false :: l2 => badd (badd l1 l2) l2
  end %list.

Lemma bsucc_correct l: value (bsucc l) = 1 + value l.
Proof.
  cbn.
  functional induction (bsucc l).
  all: cbn.
  all: lia.
Qed.

Lemma badd_correct l r: value (badd l r) = value l + value r.
Proof.
  cbn.
  functional induction (badd l r).
  all: cbn.
  all: try rewrite bsucc_correct.
  all: lia.
Qed.
```